# why the increase in number of features (inputs) does not increase the model performance?

Tags: deep-learning, regression

I have developed a LSTM model for ozone forecasting.
My first set of inputs is made of the temperature and relative humidity.
The second set I added the solar radiation and wind velocity to the first inputs.
With the second set inputs, the model performance is nearly the same as the model with the first set of inputs.
Is there any scientific explanation to this model behavior?

Comment: You just had 2 numbers as input and 1 number as output?  Or is it temperature map and humidity map?

Comment: Yes, two inputs (like two columns) for the first set, and four inputs for the second set.

Comment: You say it is nearly the same, so there is a difference and the performance does increase, right?
I would note that if the error is already low, improving the model just a bit is already an achievement. Also, you cannot expect that performance scales well with the number of model inputs.

Comment: Could you enlighten more about why I can not expect that the performance scales well with the number of inputs?